# Automate nested variable dump in VS2015 debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, automation, heap-dump

Currently I'm looking into a 'minidump with heap'.  I would like to write a unit test reproducing the crash, but therefore I need the data that lead to the crash.

Using the Visual Studio debugger, I can 'watch' the offending data structures, but they are quite big (>10k objects) and complex (using lists of lists of...) and I would love to dump these data into some readable format somehow.

The structure looks like this

```
struct Bottom {
   int x, y, z;
};
struct Mid {
    std::list<Bottom> bottoms;
};
struct Top {
    std::list<Mid> mids;
};
```

Is there a way I can write a macro/extension/... to extract e.g. all `x, y, z` data from the heap dump?

Is there another debugger that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could view the data structures in VS debugger Watch window, but it was complex as your requirement. If so, one idea is that you could create [custom view of native objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/09/28/debug-visualizers-in-visual-c-2015/), so you could view it easily even if use the same debugging Watch window.